# Why do the training drone's shots not bounce off the lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, a-new-hope

In Star Wars, blaster shots always reflect off the lightsaber as seen in so many different scenes. In A New Hope, while Luke is using the training drone on the Falcon the training drone's lasers are absorbed by the lightsaber. What is the reason the drone's shots are absorbed instead of bouncing?

I mean obviously they didn't want the shots bouncing around the Falcon in the movie, but does anyone know the technical reason for why they don't?

Comment: Because it's a *training* drone  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lightsabers are essentially plasma blades.

Plasma has a strong magnetic field surrounding it.

Blaster bolts are also plasma with some mechanic to keep them from dispersing over longer distance.

The fields interact, so the bolt can be reflected.

The training shots are "made of" electricity (electrons) that are only meant for short distances and those will disperse when hitting a magnetic field.

Comment: Are there sources to back up your claim that the remote uses electricity (and blasters don't)?

Comment: that blaster bolts are plasma was something i read on here. He gets hit by some training bolts and the shock him (thats in the film), so there has to be some electric current involved.

Comment: I disagree - it shocks him because it's a very low power stun, not enough to kill and not enough to actually stun, but enough to be painful. The standard issue Stormtrooper E-11 rifle uses the same ammo type set to kill or stun.

Comment: Agreed with @thegreatjedi. Electricity would never travel like it does in the mentioned scene without a medium to travel over. It would have arced like lightening, or even a small static shock does.

Comment: ^ Yeap. See Force Lightning. If that's not electricity, I don't know what is.

Answer (score 10):

## The low energy plasma blasts are absorbed by the lightsaber on contact

[image]

Being a *training* remote, its blasts are less powerful than normal blasters.

When any blast hits a saber blade, some of the energy is absorbed into the blade and then, if the blast was strong enough, the excess energy is reflected off the blade into a different direction.

Blasts that weren't that powerful to begin with, like the training remote, would simply be absorbed rather than bouncing off in a different direction.

This is supported by the Wookieepedia page on [Remotes](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Remote):

> Many Force-users (such as the Jedi Younglings) used remotes as training tools to hone blaster defense abilities by deflecting **the remote's low energy plasma blasts** with their lightsabers.

The fact that it says **low energy *plasma* blasts** supports the explanation provided above. The remote's *low* energy blasts are absorbed on contact. Normal combat blasters would have *high* energy blasts that can't be fully absorbed on contact and thus they are reflected off into a different direction.

[image]

---

<sub>NOTE: [Eumel's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110857/54827) claims the remote fires bolts of electricity rather than plasma. That, however, is contradicted by the Wookieepedia page on [Remotes](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Remote), which states remotes fire "low energy **plasma** blasts".</sub>